OpenSSL build generates empty header files
I am following the steps here:
1. Install Perl: DONE
2. Install NASM: DONE
3. Make sure both Perl and NASM are on your %PATH%: DONE
4. vcvarsall.bat x64: DONE //then mkdir build && cd build.
//5. perl Configure VC-WIN64A: This makes nmake fails as it's complaining about using a a x86 windows powerchell to build a x64 target hence I ended up building a WIN32 below and using it in my x64 library.
5. perl.exe ../Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=D:/dest/deps/openssl --openssldir=D:/dest/deps/openssl: DONE
6. nmake, nmake test, nmake install: DONE

Once all this done I can see the libssl.lib and  libcrypto.lib, I then add this two to the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES in my exe library cmake. Then when building (including boost in manin.cpp) I get a lot of errors .
Please note when I check my openssl/include I see all new generated .hpp files empty .
Could you please help make this build? Are empty hpp files expected? Is my build steps wrong?
I am using Windows PowerShell, when calling cl I get: 

Why are you going through the torture that is building OpenSSL yourself? Use Conan or vcpkg to build it for you.

Thank you. I don't want to use external packages :) I did same with boost and works perfectly.

Shrug. I would look into what part of the process generates those files and see why they turned out to be zero bytes, then..

I just noticed that your prefix and installation directory are the same. don't do that. Or don't run make install.
